# How to list aliases (“alias” command) from within a script

Tags: bash, alias

I’d like to execute the “alias” command from within a script. It’s under the “Settings” area for the user. I can execute “env” but would like to follow that with their set aliases that they/I would see via the “alias” command. Is there a way to do this?
I’ve tried:

```
if [[ "${command}" == "L" || "${command}" == "l" ]]                     
   then
      echo " "
      echo "Environment settings (env): "
      env
      echo " "
      echo "aliases: "
      `/bin/bash;alias`
      `alias`
      `echo ${BASH_ALIASES[]}`
      /bin/bash;alias
      alias
      echo ${BASH_ALIASES[]}
      echo " "
      echo "Done with Settings. Hit Enter to continue. "
      read settings_trash
   fi
```

But I always get nothing/null or a new shell.

Comment: Thanks sudodus that was just what I needed!

Comment: You are welcome and good luck :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need *an **interactive shell** to see the aliases*.

The following example with `bash` can probably help you fix a script

```
bash -c 'alias'  # does not see any alias

bash -ic 'alias' # sees a lot of aliases (in my system)
```